# Watermarking an image that is not in the Drupal filesystem using image_style

Tags: media

I get an image through the ImageMagick PHP extension because I don't want to start the PHP `exec()` function. This works.

But I'm not managing to create a watermarked image using `image_style` because this image is not in the Drupal file system.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

As you've probably already seen about `theme_image_style()`:

> This function does not work with images outside the files directory nor with remotely hosted images. This should be in a format such as 'images/image.jpg', or using a stream wrapper such as 'public://images/image.jpg'.

There's a beta release of a module called [Imagecache External](https://drupal.org/project/imagecache_external) which claims to solve the problem:

> Imagecache External is a utility module to allow you to use imagecache(D6)/image derivatives (D7) with external images.

With that module installed your use of `theme_image_style()` would be replaced with something like:

```
print theme('imagecache_external', array('path' => $path, 'style_name'=> 'thumbnail'));
```